# Bootstrap 4 modal does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i used example from bootstrap to create modal but nothing happens?!
On button click, nothing...

script src of bootstrap is under jquery src ?

[And this example.](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#live-demo)

Have a nice day.

Comment: Btw. I used normal code structure from bootstrap 'get started' ...

Comment: We cannot troubleshoot code that we cannot review. You will need to post your code.

Comment: Because there is nothing here to see, so my answer would be from your question [Get it.](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#live-demo)

Comment: Yes is after jquery, but why use alpha version? try with stable 3.x version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">

<!--CB-modal -->
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- JS code -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<!--JS below-->


<!--modal-->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal();
  });
</script>



</html>
```